# Errors were encountered while processing please help

Tags: 14.04, apt, nmap

I installed `nmap` but when I use `apt-get update` this message appears:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
/var/cache/apt/archives/nmap_6.47-1~ppa1~u_amd64.deb
```

Comment: There's not enough information given in your question to be sure about what's going on without seeing more of the error message you got when trying to run `sudo apt-get update`.